# Read a binary file content inside RAR archive Python

Tags: python

I would like to read a binary file from a RAR archive without opening the archive.
I tried the rarfile module, which offers that feature, But not for binary files inside the archive.
I also checked patoolib, but couldn't find an option to read files without extracting them first.

Answer (score 1):

I think `rarfile` can do what you need.  It is a quirk in the API that despite opening a file within the archive from reading in `'r'` mode, it actually does read it in binary mode.

As an example, I put a random PNG image in a new RAR archive.  Then I can read it out using:

```
import rarfile
from PIL import Image

rf = rarfile.RarFile('archive.rar')
fp = rf.open('random.png')
fp.read(10)
# returns:
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00'

fp.seek(0)
img = Image.open(fp)
img.entropy()
# returns:
6.67860261799307
```